# Facebook Messenger without permissions

Tags: permissions, facebook-messenger

Facebook Messenger for Android requires a lot of permissions - like reading my SMS and other stuff. I really don't like that. Is there any fb chat application which doesn't require such permissions?

In fact i would only need a notification when there is a new message.

Comment: The Facebook app itself (not the messenger one) can notify you of new messages. You can configure it in `Facebook App > Settings > Notifications` The messenger now handles SMS as part of its functionality, hence the permission, but there's no reason to use it since the default app will do what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ChatSecure](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.guardianproject.otr.app.im) (formerly known as “Gibberbot”) with Facebook added as an XMPP account. Just enter `username@facebook.com` and your Facebook password to connect.

For even more protection of your details you can use the "Connect via Tor" option with Orbot (the Android port of Tor) to hide your location from Facebook as well.

Comment: ChatSecure doesn't require any fragile permissions. There is a litte bit of a hassle to setup facebook through XMPP, but all of the information you can find here (after clicking Pidgin): https://www.facebook.com/sitetour/chat.php.  UI is very simple. When two sides of the conversation would like to - there is possibilty to encrypt messages. This is what I was looking for, although it could look a little bit nicer. Good app! Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can do what Andrew said, or you can download App Ops and remove the permissions from the app iteself

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.colortiger.appopsinstaller&hl=en

Comment: Do not see a mention of what version of Android OP is using, the linky to Play Store is only for Android 4.3/4.4... just saying :)

Comment: Yes, and Google says it was released in error and subsequent updates to 4.4 removed the capability. So, I don't think App Ops is a viable option.

Comment: I am just giving for reference, less than 2% of devices run kit kat, so there is a good chance it will work for him.  Just because it doesn't work for you doesn't mean it wont work for him.  Plus it will allow him to keep the default Facebook Messenger app.

Comment: App Ops looks like a great idea! Unfortunately I've got older version of android - 4.1.